# Why are Deleted items showing up in my excel export from Sharepoint Calendar

Tags: calendar, excel

I created a calendar in sharepoint 2013 and everything is working fine except a few recently deleted items are showing up in the excel export.  It's listed as Deleted: 'Title of the event' in excel but it's not listed on the calendar.

Why is it showing up and how can I prevent it from exporting to excel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to get rid of them in an export. But the why is they are part of a recurring series.

SharePoint stores an event series as one item, even though it shows as multiple events in views. Until you change one of the events - if you delete an event from the series, or change a single event of the series to a new time, then SharePoint writes a new item to track that. Those are what you are seeing...

You'd have to do some Excel VB code to remove the Deleted: events. But that would make your 'data' incorrect - you could still have a line that shows the full recurring series, without the information that one of those events was deleted.